# Do suggested edits to the Ruby toolbox get incorporated?

Tags: ruby

I made a suggested edit to Ruby toolbox this morning (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/modifications/2043). However, subsequent to that, I came across an unrelated suggested edit that was made slightly over a year ago (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/modifications/1676, made October 9 2014) that hasn't been dealt with.

Do suggested edits get incorporated into the Ruby toolbox?